# Passing User's aliases to root while doing "sudo su"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

Is it possible?

I could make an alias to `sudo su -;source .bashrc` but it seems like `source .bashrc` is executed in the earlier shell and not in root's sheel (Why?)

Answer (score 0):

sudo -E su

Should preserve the existing environment variables.
Hope that works for you ok.